# Cannot connect to SQL Server via Management 2012

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I would like to connect to SQL Server 2012 using Management Studio.  I can login without any issues when using windows authentication.  I created a called develop, with password develop, and I gave it all the all the database roles.  But instead of being able to logon. I get the following error:

[image]

Please Assist
Edit: Added the Names Pipes Properties screen shot

[image]

Comment: SQL Server Configuration/Enable Named Pipe.

Comment: It was already enabled

Comment: http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/356619/A-connection-was-successfully-established-with-the

Comment: Do you trying to connect to the local SQL Server or it allocated on remote server? If on remote, you must enable TCP/IP connection. The named pipe can be used only on local communication.

Comment: Im connecting on a local server